# Pyo3 panic placeholder should be replaced

Tags: python-polars

When I try

.collect(streaming=True)

Get pyo3_runtime.PanicException: placeholder should be replaced

My below code work if collect streaming False but panic if streaming True

Import polars as pl
Import pandas as pd

right_ldf = pl.from_pandas(pd.read_excel("file.xls")).lazy()

left_ldf = pl.scan_csv("file.csv").filter(pl.col("col2") = 2).with_columns(col3=pl.when(pl.col("col1") = 1).then("result").join(right_ldf, on="col1", how="inner").collect(streaming=True)

The actual code there was many node of "with columns" or "filter" and "join" is the last node then collect. That code get panic

But if I move the join node before "with columns" or "filter", there was no panic ex. Right after scan_csv node

What I expected is there was no panic wherever I placed the join node as long as no col calculation related to right_ldf, is this bug or there is a trick to resolve this issue

Comment: Can you make an issue? This is a bug.

Comment: Here's the link https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues